# Import luigi throws SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-2.7, luigi

`import luigi` is the first line of my program. But IDE throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1415, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "task.py", line 2, in <module>
    import luigi
  File "/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from luigi import task
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/task.py', 145, 21, 'class Task(metaclass=Register):\n'))
```

Comment: [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) is a **Python (3.6, 3.7 tested) package** that helps you build complex pipelines of batch jobs.

Comment: @OlvinRoght that's what the GitHub repo says, but readthedocs documentation disagrees. Curious.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, your error caused by using wrong python version. It's obvious, cause [*metaclasses*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) have been added in python 3.0 ([PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115)).

Comment: @OlvinRoght, thanks for your answers. The luigi version is 3.0.0 and degrade it to 2.1.1 solves the problem.

Comment: @zqiang0zh, probably it will be better to upgrade python version instead, cause since 2020 started python 2.7 is [no longer supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).